# Convert object with methods to string in Javascript (for Photoshop)

Tags: javascript, object, serialization, photoshop

I have a global object I use in my Photoshop scripts. It has properties and methods like this:

```
var Obj = {};
Obj.str = "this is a string";
Obj.swissKnife = new SwissKnife(); // custom object with it's own methods
Obj.swissKnife.aMethod = function() { return "this is a method"; };
```

I need to convert this entire object to a string.

In Photoshop, in order to display a palette (non-modal) dialog, allowing the user to continue interacting with the application (I need them to select an area with the marquee tool before continuing), you must send a message back to Photoshop through BridgeTalk. When doing so, the code you're wanting to send must be a string, like this:

```
var title = "Select image";
var message = "Select image to protect with marquee tool, then click continue.";
var bt = new BridgeTalk();
bt.target = "photoshop";
bt.body = "var w = new Window('palette', '" + title + "', [0, 0, 400, 100]); \
                w.add('statictext', [5,5,390,50], '" + message + "'); \
                okButton = w.add('button', [5,40,205,90], 'GO!'); \
                w.center(); \
                okButton.onClick = function() { \
                    w.close(); \
                    obj = " + obj + "; \
                    #include \"/c/script.jsx\"; \
                }; \
                w.show();";
bt.send();
```

I need the object obj to be available (with all its properties and methods) to the next script that I load, /c/script.jsx. So I need a way to evaluate the entire obj object into a string to be written into the obj = declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the objectToXML method in Stdlib.js of the xtools library here: http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html